# iTunes Store Not Showing

Tags: itunes, mojave, itunes-store

Whenever i try to go to the iTunes store, it loads and acts like something will come up, but its completely blank in the middle where the songs are displayed. It still lets me search but nothing comes up.

[image]

It is v12.9.5.5 on Mojave

Comment: Same problem was posted [3 months ago](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356146/itunes-store-is-completely-blank), reportedly suffering from the issue through multiple macOS versions, with no solution found. Have you tried in safe mode? How about in a new/guest user account?

Comment: @grg Yes, I checked that question then decided to open it up. I tried in safe mode but nothing changed. However I did try with guest user and am able to display the store in iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Not practical/applicable solution here:

I somehow needed to delete my iTunes music archive. Then it asked me to login my account. After login, everything showed up.